# Is it legal to refuse to let a student test out of classes in Michigan?

Tags: united-states, education, michigan

I am an aspiring mathematics student at a public high school in Midland, Michigan.

I have studied over the summer 8 AP courses, and filled out a variety of paperwork in advance to test out of these AP courses.

The Michigan Merit Curriculum Law has a section referring to schools allowing students to test out, and requiring it.

After reading it, I had the impression that I could graduate with the credits gained from the test-out.

Today, I had a meeting with the principal, and I was told that there did not exist tests for skipping the courses I filled out paperwork for, and even if there were, I would never be allowed to graduate early.

Is this legal, and in compliance with the Michigan Merit Curriculum Law?

Comment: https://www.michigan.gov/documents/mde/Complete_MMC_FAQ_August_2014_467323_7.pdf "Local boards of education can establish additional graduation requirements beyond those in the MMC and the total number of credits required for graduation."

Comment: That explains the graduation requirements. But it doesn’t explain how they won’t let me test out of classes.

Comment: Not trying to provide an answer in the comment, just a link to relevant information.

Comment: I. for one, need clarification , please. Does "test out of classes" mean sit an exam as an external candidate, rather than officially as a student of the school running the exams?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin No, I am a student of the school in question.

Comment: @JohnClever Thanks and does this boil down to your being told there did not exist tests for skipping the courses I filled out paperwork for, and even if there were, I would never be allowed to graduate early, or is about something else?

Either way, does "test out of classes" mean sit an exam as an external candidate, rather than officially as a student of the school running the exams?